# K2 SEF URls adds menu and category hierarchy

Tags: k2

I just installed Joomla 3.9 and K2. Created few items in k2. But looks like URL generated by K2 is not really SEF Url. when categories are published as menu items

1. I enabled SEF URLs in Global Configuration.
2. In K2 configuration, I added the following configuration under SEO

Url for the items generated fine when their category is not added in main menu as seen below:

```
/parent-category/sub-category1/sub-category2/article-title
```

Now as soon as I add the main menu category hierarchy for category "sub-category2", url now changes to the following:

```
/parent-category/sub-category1/sub-category2/parent-category/sub-category1/sub-category2/article-title
```

As seen, it adds the menu hierarchy as well as my category hierarchy to the url.

How can I get rid of main menu hierarchy from the url and only keep the category hierarchy so that my article url is clean?

Thanks

[image: K2 SEO Configuration]

Thanks

Comment: Ok..I am little closer now..One of my menu item contained a timestamp in alias . I removed it and now url looks something like this: /parent-category/sub-category1/sub-category2/sub-category3/item/32-item-title. It still contains "item" in the url as well as article id. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question body to include your updated achievements then delete your comment.  Ideally the "full story" should wholly and solely exist in the question.  (And please remove the "thanks" when you edit)

Comment: Googling "k2 remove item from url" provided many hits: eg. https://geekflare.com/remove-item-from-k2-joomla/

Comment: I changed the question based on comments. Thanks